# linear algebra texts suggestions

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I am looking for a textbook about linear algebra. I want one with a pure math/algebraic approach and not one with a geometric or a applied/numerical approach. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: How about Halmos finite dimensional vector spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serge Lang, Linear algebra. Springer-Verlag. A popular book at an introductory level

W. Greub. Linear algebra. Springer-Verlag. A really abstract presentation of linear algebra.